# How to install a text file with a MonoTouch app

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

How can I install a text file as part of a MonoTouch app? I know how to create, write to, and read from a text file in the app's Documents folder, but I want to install a text file previously created (outside of the app). I added a text file to the MonoTouch project, and marked it as "Content", but after I deploy to the simulator, I do not see my file in any of the app's folders.

Comment: I just created a new iPhone MonoTouch Project in MonoDevelop, added a "Documents" folder, added a "MyText.txt" file to that folder, set the build action on the text file to "Content", compiled it, and there's a "./Documents/MyText.txt" file in my app bundle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829954/write-to-a-file-in-monotouch

Answer (score 1):

Are you checking the right place? It will be in the app bundle which is typically at:

> ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/User/Applications/{guid}/

Right click on your app name and select *"show package contents"*.

Comment: I wish I could vote this answer up 1000x. I have been pulling my hair out for 2 hours trying to figure out why I was not seeing my files in `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/{guid}/Documents`. "Show package contents"! Genius! Thank you.