# Best way to persist an XML file on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, file-io, xamarin.ios

I'm using MonoTouch and also System.Data to create a DataSet (just xml to those not familiar) for simple data binding.  Data on my app is minimal so no need to go all out with SQLLite.  The dataset use makes it easy to pass via web services for cloud sync.

I serialize the DataSet to the personal folder on save and of course read this file when the app starts up to load up the user's data.  I've had issues where this file is becoming corrupt and I'm not sure why.  I assume file I/O may be slow on these devices and that could be the cause, I'm not sure, but it is happening.

I'm also concerned that maybe iTunes is passing this file back and forth between the PC/MAC when the user syncs their devices with iTunes, which may be the cause of the corruption?

I want to prevent this device file from syncing with iTunes and also reliably persist it.  I'm using the NSFile.Save option to save it to the device.  I'm thinking since it's a text file maybe I could more safely store it in the standard user settings area instead?  This would prevent it from being synced by itunes, I presume?

What is the most reliable and safe way to handle this file i/o for the xml dataset storage?

Thank you.

Comment: What path are you using to store the document? Have you read [these](http://wiki.monotouch.net/HowTo/Files/HowTo%3a_Store_Files) guidelines on where to store files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using MonoTouch. Isn't it simply a matter of calling DataSet.WriteXml() with a FileStream object ready to write to a document in your Documents folder?

That Documents folder is backed up to iTunes. It's not synced, but it helps if your user is restoring their phone (because they bricked it, lost it, whatever). It doesn't explain why it's corrupt.

The only thing that I can think of why it's corrupt is because it took too long for your app to write it. There's a limited time from the point where the user exits the app until it's closed down, to prevent apps from keeping the system hostage and deteriorate user experience.

If writing the whole dataset takes too long, you want to think about minimizing that. Perhaps you can just store the data, and not the schema. Or you can devise a way to store only the deltas on exit and reconcile when the user has loaded your app again.

You can also prevent complete loss of data by writing to a second file, and when that operation completes delete the old file and rename. That way, the next time you start up if the write operation didn't complete, the old file would still be there and the user would have only lost their more recent changes.

In any case, if your data gets too big for a simple write operation to complete, you should look at different options such as sqlite.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably to just save the XML as text. It's as simple as File.WriteAllText(...) - there's no reason to go to NSFile for this. That's part of the advantage of MonoTouch :)

Regarding syncing, here's the rule:

- If you keep the file in the user's documents folder (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments and Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal BOTH point to the user's doc folder), then it's going to get backed up whenever the user syncs with iTunes.

There's nothing wrong with this. It persists the data between sessions and makes it recoverable if something goes wrong with the user's phone and they need to restore from a backup. Since your question is about *persisting* an XML file on the phone, this is what you want.

As for the iTunes question, there's no problem with speed and syncing because your app isn't going to be running while the phone is syncing. The file will either have been saved or it won't. Any corruption that takes place is happening *while your app is running*.

Reasons for files getting corrupted can include:

- Not saving before the user quits. You get a chance to do this.
- Not gracefully handling an incoming phone call. The system warns you about this as well.

iTunes definitely isn't corrupting your file. If that were the case, iOS apps would all be broken. It could be happening on your dev machine for whatever reason, but I've never seen this happen elsewhere, and I've done quite a bit of iOS development.

If you'd like a tutorial on reading and writing files, I posted [an answer in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829954/write-to-a-file-in-monotouch/1844772#1844772).

It's lengthy, but the point was to answer as many questions as I could so nobody would be left hanging or confused.

A nice thing about iOS devices is that you're back (for most apps) in the one-person-at-a-time world. You're writing apps where you don't have to worry about 5,000 people trying to use your web-based app at the same time (that's not always true, but... you get the point). As a result, you can do things that you might normally consider bad for performance, but you're unlikely to see any performance problems (as long as the file you're saving is either small enough to be saved quickly or you're saving in the background on another thread - you never want to block the main (UI) thread with a heavy IO operation).

If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Rory.  I'm using the DataSet.WriteXml and .ReadXml methods.  I'm going to change things so I'm only persisting the data, not the schema, then merge in the data when the app is run.  This will save some time.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of frameworks are read-only, but I've found that GDataXMLNode from http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/ works very well read/write.

Having said that, on the iPhone you'd do yourself a big favour using Core Data with a SQLLite backend. :-) Apple has done all this for you and optimized it more than any of us every will

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 0):

Consider using SQLite, I'd go for something like

- http://www.taimila.com/entify/ (not tried yet)
- catnap orm
- or Faks sqlite-net on google code (using this in a few apps)

entify - if it does what it says it can do - looks really good.

persisting XML on the iPhone as a means to store and access data is a nause you dont want to get into. I wrote about it here http://iwayneo.blogspot.com/2010/08/festival-star-history-serialization-as.html

Comment: in the comments of the Entify forumns, it says that it only worked with the emulator, not with a deployed device.  Has anyone verified it works yet?